# Project/workspace structure for multiple apps with CocoaPods

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I'm about to migrate my app to use [CocoaPods](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods). My current directory structure looks like the diagram below. I have one workspace that contains 3 projects (`ipad`, `ipod`, `common`). There are build targets in the `ipad` and `ipod` projects with dependencies on the `common` project.

```
MyGreatApp
|
+-- MyGreatApp.xcworkspace
|
+-- ipad
|    |
|    +-- ipad.xcodeproj
|    +-- (source code)
|
+-- ipod
|    |
|    +-- ipod.xcodeproj
|    +-- (source code)
|
+-- common
     |
     +-- common.xcodeproj
     +-- (source code)
```

My question is, how should I migrate this to CocoaPods? It looks like CocoaPods create a new workspace for each `Podfile` that you create. I'd like to keep my 3-project workspace structure because it seems like it keeps everything together nicely. Should I create a `Podfile` for each project with targets and a `Specfile` for the common project? How do I set this up in XCode then?

Answer (score 52):

In the latest version at the time of this post, you need to have your podfile in the following format:

```
workspace 'Test'
xcodeproj 'iphone/iphone.xcodeproj'
xcodeproj 'iphone2/iphone2.xcodeproj'

target :iphone do
    platform :ios, '6.0'
    pod 'RestKit'
    xcodeproj 'iphone/iphone.xcodeproj'
end

target :iphone2 do
    platform :ios, '6.0'
    pod 'RestKit'
    xcodeproj 'iphone2/iphone2.xcodeproj'
end
```

I verified that this is working for multiple projects in an existing workspace.

See this post for more details: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/738

Comment: So yeah I was having the same problem. I went through this thread: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/738
The main point is to specify the workspace and all sub-projects in the beginning of the Podfile and then, the sub-project again for all targets. 
Which exactly what you did! thanks :)

Comment: Great answer, thanks! Got pods working for both OS X and iOS projects in same workspace.

Comment: thank you, perfect answer! this should def be added to the official documentation!

Comment: Why are the project references specified twice? And couldn't it extract the platform from the project file?

Comment: Oh, so the platform is for the static library to be built. I deleted all my top level xcodeproj's and it said it couldn't work out which one to use so I added only one of them back and it seems to work.